# Why sum doesn't work here?

Tags: java, sum

Here I am with another basic question, in follow of my last question . I hope these questions don't annoy anyone because they are very basic .
First I get names as inputs then change them to integer then I need to sum them and put them in equation which this Sum doesn't work

Thanks before for your time and help.

```
package loveindex;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class LoveIndex {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi = scan.nextLine();
    testi = testi.toUpperCase();
    char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
    for(char ch:ascii1){
      //  System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
        int[] a = {(int)ch};
        int all = IntStream.of(a).sum(); // >>> here it shows an error and the quick fix as always is just a bigger mess ...
        System.out.println("The sum is " + a);
    }


    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi2 = scan.nextLine();
    testi2 = testi2.toUpperCase();
    char[] ascii2 = testi2.toCharArray();
    for(char ch:ascii2){
        System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
    }
  scan.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you using java 8 ?

Comment: the part which I already have mentioned on the codes as a comment once it shows error for the syntax then when I use quick fix it creates a class and then it shows error for the other part of the syntax ".of"

Comment: i checked from java.com it says 7 update 71

Comment: OK, but `IntStream` and `sum` are a Java 8 thing.  You'll need to redesign this if you're using Java 7.  Or upgrade to Java 8.

Comment: I updated to 8 but still have the same problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    String testi = scan.nextLine();
    testi = testi.toUpperCase();
    char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    for (char ch : ascii1) {
        sum += ch;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    scan.close();
}
```

As requested, example with ongoing inputs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
        String testi = scan.nextLine();
        testi = testi.toUpperCase();
        char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        for (char ch : ascii1) {
            sum += ch;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the right answer :D thanks again ... now I have to duplicate this code in order to get 2 inputs from 2 different people ...

Comment: Or put a while loop round it and have as many as you want, added to answer.

Comment: :: It is a program for Love index so I will get only 2 names ... any way I will have new question for some random inputs ...

Answer (score 1):

You are re declaring the variable "a" right after you declare it.  Also you shouldn't need to declare int[] a as an array when you are just casting a char to an int.  I would move int a outside of your for each loop and initialize it to 0.  Then move your system print of the sum outside the for each loop also.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
String testi = scan.nextLine();
testi = testi.toUpperCase();
char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
int a = 0;
for(char ch:ascii1){
  //  System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
    a += (int)ch;

}
   System.out.println("The sum is " + a);

   System.out.println("Testing Scanner, write something: ");
     String testi2 = scan.nextLine();
      testi2 = testi2.toUpperCase();
     char[] ascii2 = testi2.toCharArray();
for(char ch:ascii2){
    System.out.println((int)ch + "  ");
}
  scan.close();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense, even if you were compiling it with Java 8:

```
char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
for(char ch:ascii1){
  //  System.out.println((int)ch+"  ");
    int[] a = {(int)ch};
    int all = IntStream.of(a).sum(); // >>> here it shows an error and the quick fix as always is just a bigger mess ...
    System.out.println("The sum is " + a);
}
```

For each character of the input String, You are creating an array of a single character casted to int, and then you compute the sum of that single int.

Instead, you probably want to sum all the characters together :

```
char[] ascii1 = testi.toCharArray();
int sum = 0;
for(char ch:ascii1){
    sum += ch;
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: The cast to int is not required, the char is automatically upcast.